# How to extract a character from a text file containing a dot-matrix character set?

Tags: c#, dot-matrix

I have a file gg.txt with this text:

```
L = 4
H = 5
T = E
 #  ##   ## ##  ### ###  ## # # ###  ## # # #   # # ###  #  ##   #  ##   ## ### # # # # # # # # # # ### ### 
# # # # #   # # #   #   #   # #  #    # # # #   ### # # # # # # # # # # #    #  # # # # # # # # # #   #   # 
### ##  #   # # ##  ##  # # ###  #    # ##  #   ### # # # # ##  # # ##   #   #  # # # # ###  #   #   #   ## 
# # # # #   # # #   #   # # # #  #  # # # # #   # # # # # # #    ## # #   #  #  # # # # ### # #  #  #       
# # ##   ## ##  ### #    ## # # ###  #  # # ### # # # #  #  #     # # # ##   #  ###  #  # # # #  #  ###  #
```

As you can see, it's an alphabet. L is the character length; H is the character height. (They will always stay 4 and 5.) T is the character that I want print,. So, if T=E, I need to print only the image for E in the console.

```
### 
#   
##  
#   
###
```

If I will change T in txt, for example to B, the program will print B. I don't have any ideas how to do this or start, here is my starting code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string[] fileContent = File.ReadAllLines("gg.txt");

        Console.WriteLine(string.Join("", fileContent));
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: do you want to print one character at a time or even word and sencteces?

Comment: `As you can see, its alphabet.` - had to look way to long to realise the letters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you want to keep only the substrings part of a given character so if T is a char and there is nothing else in the file than what you showed:

```
int charIndex = (int)T - (int)'A';
int startPos = charIndex * L;

foreach (string line in File.ReadLines("gg.txt"))
{
    Console.WriteLine(line.Substring(startPos, L));
}
```

Note that you probably want to validate T and L before executing this.

Comment: ye, i want keep only character what i need print T

Comment: @GintarsLazda Then this should work (I updated the code since I had forgotten Substring takes a length in parameter and not an end position)

Comment: but T is located in .txt file

Comment: damn my english is so low, c# say that name T does not exist in the current context

Comment: but why c# say that T does not exist if (int)T

Comment: In the code I posted, I assumed T and L were input parameters, not to be read from the file

Comment: startIndex cannot be larger than lenght of string , ArgumetOutoFRangeException

Comment: If you add: `char T = 'e'; int L = 4;` before the posted code, does it work?

Comment: nom c# say again that startIndex cannot be larger than lenght of string

Comment: did you try this code on a file that does not have the first 3 lines?

Comment: just a sec  i will try

Comment: no, it doesnt work

Comment: What does not work?

Comment: i delete from txt file 3 first lines, add  int L = 4;
            char T ='e'; , but it doesnt work

Comment: sorry, add `T='E'` (capital E)

Comment: System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'startIndex cannot be larger than length of string.
Parameter name: startIndex'

Comment: oh, now its work!

Comment: That's why I insisted on validating the parameters ;)

Answer (score 1):

Please note the code above has no error checking at all.

```
using (var sr = new StreamReader(@"c:\gg.txt"))
{
    var l = int.Parse(sr.ReadLine().Split('=')[1]);
    var h = int.Parse(sr.ReadLine().Split('=')[1]);
    var t = sr.ReadLine().Split('=')[1].Trim()[0];
    int pos = t - 'A';

    for (int i = 0; i < h; i++)
    {
        var line = sr.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine(line.Substring(l*pos,l));
    }
}
```

See full code here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/FuM5ci

Answer (score 0):

based on the previous solution  i managed to extend to more than one letter(not the most elegant way but it works)

[image]

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;
using System.Globalization;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string line;
            int rowCount = 0;


            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"gg.txt"))
            {
                var charLenght = int.Parse(sr.ReadLine().Split('=')[1]);
                var charHeight = int.Parse(sr.ReadLine().Split('=')[1]);
                var whatToPrint = sr.ReadLine().Split('=')[1].Trim();
                //foreach (var letter in whatToPrint)
                for (int i = 0; i < whatToPrint.Length; i++)

                {
                    int pos = whatToPrint[i] - 'A';

                    for (int j = 0; j < charHeight; j++)
                    {

                        line = sr.ReadLine();
                        Console.SetCursorPosition(charLenght * i, j);
                        int left = Console.CursorLeft, top = Console.CursorTop; left = left; top = top;
                        if (whatToPrint[i] == (char)32)
                            break;

                        else
                            Console.WriteLine(line.Substring(charLenght * pos, charLenght)); 


                    }
                    // back to start of the text file and skip the first 3 rows
                    sr.DiscardBufferedData();
                    sr.BaseStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);


                    for (int l = 0; l < 3; l++)
                    {
                        sr.ReadLine();
                    }

                }
            }

            Console.ReadLine();

        }
    }
```